# Bind multiple remote objects to the same RMI registry

Tags: rmi, remote-server

I have a client program that calls remote methods on a server. Now, I want to create 3 different servers based upon the IP address sent by the client.

Question: Should I create 3 different Remote objects and bind them to the same registry. or should I create 3 different Remote objects and bind them to their respective registry ??

What I am doing right now is one Remote object and binding all 3 objects to the same registry.

Remote obj=UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this,2026);
Registry r=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2026);
r.bind("NA", obj);
r.bind("EU", obj);
r.bind("AS", obj);

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense. You don't bind hosts to registries. You bind remote objects to names in registries. It also doesn't have anything to do with your actual question. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I worked with RMI; be that as it may, my advice is to bind all objects in the same registry, which, I guess, you are already doing.

Comment: Hi Robert, 
I am binding the same object with one single registry. Did you mean to create 3 different objects ?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you need to accomplish. If all clients make calls on the same server object, then create one remote object. If each client needs to call a separate server object, then create three different remote objects. Of course, even if there are multiple remote objects, they can share resources; they don't need to be totally independent.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use multiple Registries in the same host, especially if they are all started by the same JVM. Use a single one. Multiple entries in a single hash table inside one Registry are a lot cheaper than multiple Registries.