# 3 remote objects bound to same RMI registry

Tags: object, client, rmi

```
GameServer ob1=new GameServer();
GameServer ob2=new GameServer();
GameServer ob3=new GameServer();
Remote objNA=UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(ob1,2026);
Remote objEU=UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(ob2,2026);
Remote objAS=UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(ob3,2026);
Registry r=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2026);
r.rebind("NA", objNA);
r.rebind("EU", objEU);
r.rebind("AS", objAS);
```

I am creating 3 different remote objects on the server and binding them to the same registry. The purpose is to have 3 different hash tables one for each server. Now when I am calling one server from the client based upon its IP address... by using Naming.lookup(NA).... I am not able to access the Hashtables of other 2 servers.

Any suggestions how to access the other two ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind multiple remote objects to the same RMI registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516906/bind-multiple-remote-objects-to-the-same-rmi-registry)

Comment: Define 'unable'. What happens instead? How are you looking up the other two remote objects?

Comment: Depending up on the IP address the user enters on the client side

Comment: That's not even a sentence, let alone an answer.

Comment: @EJP - This is a class assignment where we let the user enter the IP address where he wants to connect. Does that makes it a sentence now ?

Comment: It makes it a sentence, but it still doesn't answer my question. Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
r.rebind("NA", objNA);
r.rebind("EU", objEU);
r.rebind("AS", objAS);
```

That means you can retrieve stubs for those objects via:

```
GameServerInterface ifNA = (GameServerInterface)r.lookup("NA");
GameServerInterface ifEU = (GameServerInterface)r.lookup("EU");
GameServerInterface ifAS = (GameServerInterface)r.lookup("AS");
```